# Calling an External VBA from VBScript

Tags: vba, vbscript, ms-word, ms-office

I am using a program called mathtype to pull some equation objects out of a word document. I've written code in VBA that works perfectly using their API, but I have to translate it to a VBScript file. I have looked all over google, but have not found any solution on how (If it is even possible) to call a VBA library from VBScript.

VBScript can't see the MathTypeSDK Objects/Functions.

If not possible, how would I encase the macro I need to run in a globally available word file and call it from the VBScript?

**Edit: Got it! Unfortunately the approaches below, while helpful, did not work for my situation. I found something closer: Embedding the macro in a global file and calling it through the Word Objects Run command.
objWord.Run "Normal.NewMacros.RunMain"**

Comment: You could hook up your macro to the "open" event in a Word document, then just open the word file from VBScript.  It all depends on how much interaction you need between the VBA and VBscript code.  Is the Mathtype code in a dll or is it a VBA add-in?

Comment: Basically I just need one class (I could just redefine it in my VBScript) and one function (this is the troubling part) from a "global template" VBA project (The reference in VBA is to a .dot).

Answer (score 3):

Here is an approach which might work for you. I tested this simple example.

Class "clsTest" in file "Tester.docm":

```
Public Sub Hello()
    MsgBox "Hello"
End Sub
```

Class "Instancing" is marked "PublicNotCreatable".

Module in "Tester.docm":

```
Public Function GetClass() As clsTest
    Set GetClass = New clsTest
End Function
```

In your vbscript:

```
Dim fPath, fName

fPath = "C:\Documents and Settings\twilliams\Desktop\"
fName = "Tester.docm"

Dim wdApp, o

Set wdApp = CreateObject("word.application")
wdApp.visible=true
wdapp.documents.open fPath & fName

Set o = wdApp.Run("GetClass")
o.Hello

Set o=nothing
```

Again - I only tested this simple example: you'll have to adapt it to your situation and try it out.

Answer (score 2):

Word-VBA was not made to create reusable libraries, I suppose (for usage in external programs).

One way to reuse existing Word-VBA code is, however, run Word via `WScript.Shell.Run` using the `/m<macroname>` command line switch (see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/210565/en-us for details). This, has the restriction that evertime you need to call a specific macro, a Word process is started again, running that macro, and ends afterwards. Means, if you need just one call to your Word.VBA for a specfific task, this may be ok, but if you need a lot of interprocess communication between your VBScript and your VBA macro, you should look for a different solution.